# What is an efficient way to render objects in different layers for my java game

Tags: java, graphics, render

I am learning how to make games in java and eclipse. I want the game i'm making now (a simple platform game) to have objects drawn in different layers.  I want the player to be in front, the enemies in the middle and the platforms/blocks to be in the back.

All of the objects in my game have a render layer int in their constructors. The current way i'm going about render layers is having seperate render functions for each render layer that runs through all the objects and checks their renderLayer value.  If the object has the correct renderLayer value it will be drawn if not, it won't be drawn and will be drawn in the function that needs it's corresponding renderLayer value.

Here is the code:

```
public void render1(Graphics g){
    for(int i = 0; i < object.size(); i++){
        GameObject tempObject = object.get(i);
        if(tempObject.renderLayer == 1){
            tempObject.render(g);
        }
    }
}
```

I have one of these render functions for each layer.
In the game loop, the render functions are called like this:

```
handler.render1(g);
handler.render2(g);
handler.render3(g);
```

My method works exactly how I want it too but, the problem is that my game sometimes lags or stutters and the cpu usage on my PC goes up to 50-60%.  I'm fairly certain that a modern computer shouldn't have issues running this game.

Is there a better way of going about this? Do I have the right idea or am I doing this completely wrong?

Help is really appreciated! Thanks a ton!

Comment: There could be many reasons for this. Are you culling all the objects that are outside the frame? Have you tried to time your render code for a single frame? Is the render time more or less constant? How many frames per second does that give you? What about the memory usage, do you create a lot of objects for each frame, how is the garbage collection handling this?

Comment: I don't think I'm doing any of these.  The fps is very high in the thousands.

Comment: I wanted to do culling but, I'm not sure how to get the objects back in the game when they come back in frame.

Comment: I think you should look into changing your code so that it produces frames in a rate that match the frame rate of your monitor. Thousand frames per second is way too much. It should probably be 60 fps or so.